# Make Bootstrap 3 Tabs Responsive

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Currently, when you set up tabs in Bootstrap 3, the tabs are not responsive.

This:

[image]

Turns into this:

[image]

**CSS. Fixing how it looks is easy, just  removing the float, etc. at the max-width. However, the content is disjointed from the tab, so a stack of tabs will work like tabs but on smaller viewports you may or may not see the change in content.**

---

This is the basic html for making a tabbed navigation:

```
      <!--begin tabs going in wide content -->
       <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="maincontent" role="tablist">
          <li class="active"><a href="#home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
             <a href="#" id="myTabDrop1" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
             <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="myTabDrop1">
                <li><a href="#dropdown1" tabindex="-1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">@fat</a></li>
                <li><a href="#dropdown2" tabindex="-1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">@mdo</a></li>
             </ul>
          </li>
       </ul><!--/.nav-tabs.content-tabs -->


       <div class="tab-content">

          <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">
             <p>Home Content : ...</p>
          </div><!--/.tab-pane -->

          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">
             <p>Profile Content : ...</p>
          </div><!--/.tab-pane -->

          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="dropdown1">
             <p>Dropdown1 - ...</p>
          </div><!--/.tab-pane -->

          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="dropdown2">
             <p>Dropdown 2 - ...</p>
          </div><!--/.tab-pane -->

       </div><!--/.tab-content -->
```

*How do you turn the Tabs into the Accordion or Collapse so that it's small viewport friendly?*

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Bootstrap tabs are not responsive out of the box. Responsive, IMO, is a style change, changing functions is Adaptive. There are a few plugins to turn the Bootstrap 3 tabs into a Collapse component. The best and most updated one is : https://github.com/flatlogic/bootstrap-tabcollapse.

Here's one way of implementing it:

### DEMO: http://jsbin.com/zibani/1/

#### EDIT: http://jsbin.com/zibani/1/edit

This turns the content into a collapse component:

[image]

**Dependencies:**

1. Bootstrap 3.2 css or higher but still in the 3 series
2. Bootstrap 3.2 jQuery or higher but still in the 3 series
3. Compatible version of bootstrap-tabcollapse.js

**HTML -- same as question with  class name addition:**

```
       <ul class="nav nav-tabs content-tabs" id="maincontent" role="tablist">
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // DEPENDENCY: https://github.com/flatlogic/bootstrap-tabcollapse
    $('.content-tabs').tabCollapse();

    // initialize tab function
    $('.nav-tabs a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab('show');
    });

});
```

**CSS -- optional for fat fingers and active states:**

```
.panel-heading {
    padding: 0
}
.panel-heading a {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px 10px;
}
.panel-heading a.collapsed {
    background: #fff
}
.panel-heading a {
    background: #f7f7f7;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.panel-heading a:after {
    content: '-'
}
.panel-heading a.collapsed:after {
    content: '+'
}
.nav.nav-tabs li a,
.nav.nav-tabs li.active > a:hover,
.nav.nav-tabs li.active > a:active,
.nav.nav-tabs li.active > a:focus {
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    outline: none;
}
.nav.nav-tabs li a {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.tab-pane {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you rejected my edits. The two links you posted are broken. Here is a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/obliviga/gpavt9h0/

Comment: There was a problem with jsbin. I had marked these private but they should be public now.

Comment: Demo link and Edit link doesn't work from the original post, but @ralph-david-abernathy demo works as expected!

Answer (score 30):

Slack has a cool way of making tabs small viewport friendly on some of their admin pages. I made something similar using bootstrap. It's kind of a tabs → dropdown.

**Demo: http://jsbin.com/nowuyi/1**

Here's what it looks like on a big viewport:
[image: as tabs]

Here's how it looks collapsed on a small viewport:

[image: collapsed dropdown]

Here's how it looks expanded on a small viewport:

[image: open dropdown]

the HTML is exactly the same as default bootstrap tabs.

There is a small JS snippet, which requires jquery (and inserts two span elements into the DOM):

```
$.fn.responsiveTabs = function() {
  this.addClass('responsive-tabs');
  this.append($('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>'));
  this.append($('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top"></span>'));

  this.on('click', 'li.active > a, span.glyphicon', function() {
    this.toggleClass('open');
  }.bind(this));

  this.on('click', 'li:not(.active) > a', function() {
    this.removeClass('open');
  }.bind(this));
};

$('.nav.nav-tabs').responsiveTabs();
```

And then there is a lot of css (less):

```
@xs: 768px;


.responsive-tabs.nav-tabs {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  height: 42px;
  overflow: visible;
  border-bottom: none;

  @media(min-width: @xs) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  }

  span.glyphicon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 14px;
    right: 22px;
    &.glyphicon-triangle-top {
      display: none;
    }
    @media(min-width: @xs) {
      display: none;
    }
  }

  > li {
    display: none;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;

    &:last-of-type > a {
      margin-right: 0;
    }

    > a {
      margin-right: 0;
      background: #fff;
      border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;

      @media(min-width: @xs) {
        margin-right: 4px;
      }
    }

    &.active {
      display: block;
      a {
        @media(min-width: @xs) {
          border-bottom-color: transparent; 
        }
        border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
        border-radius: 2px;
      }
    }

    @media(min-width: @xs) {
      display: block;
      float: left;
    }

  }

  &.open {

    span.glyphicon {
      &.glyphicon-triangle-top {
        display: block;
        @media(min-width: @xs) {
          display: none;
        }
      }
      &.glyphicon-triangle-bottom {
        display: none;
      }
    }

    > li {
      display: block;

      a {
        border-radius: 0;
      }

      &:first-of-type a {
        border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
      }
      &:last-of-type a {
        border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd really hoped to make this work with Bootstrap 5. But I can't get it to work properly. This is the method I would prefer. https://codepen.io/ThePixelPixie/pen/JjNxPog

Answer (score 12):

[image]

There is a new one: http://hayatbiralem.com/blog/2015/05/15/responsive-bootstrap-tabs/

And also Codepen sample available here: http://codepen.io/hayatbiralem/pen/KpzjOL

No needs plugin. It uses just a little css and jquery.

Here's a sample tabs markup:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-responsive">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">
            <span class="text">Tab 1</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="next">
        <a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">
            <span class="text">Tab 2</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">
            <span class="text">Tab 3</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

.. and jQuery codes are also here:

```
(function($) {

  'use strict';

  $(document).on('show.bs.tab', '.nav-tabs-responsive [data-toggle="tab"]', function(e) {
    var $target = $(e.target);
    var $tabs = $target.closest('.nav-tabs-responsive');
    var $current = $target.closest('li');
    var $parent = $current.closest('li.dropdown');
        $current = $parent.length > 0 ? $parent : $current;
    var $next = $current.next();
    var $prev = $current.prev();
    var updateDropdownMenu = function($el, position){
      $el
        .find('.dropdown-menu')
        .removeClass('pull-xs-left pull-xs-center pull-xs-right')
        .addClass( 'pull-xs-' + position );
    };

    $tabs.find('>li').removeClass('next prev');
    $prev.addClass('prev');
    $next.addClass('next');

    updateDropdownMenu( $prev, 'left' );
    updateDropdownMenu( $current, 'center' );
    updateDropdownMenu( $next, 'right' );
  });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Nice, but this implementation only makes sense (from a user experience stand point) if the headers are sequential, like Day, Week, Month, etc. Otherwise, the user will be lost if the headers are arbitrary.

Comment: but how if i want to do only for sm and xs only.. currently it just detect xs

Comment: You can change `max-width: 479px` to `max-width: 991px` or you can write more code to dynamic aproach like `nav-tabs-responsive--xs`, `nav-tabs-responsive--sm`, etc.

Answer (score 12):

I prefer a css only scheme based on horizontal scroll, like tabs on android. This's my solution, just wrap with a class nav-tabs-responsive:

```
<div class="nav-tabs-responsive">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li>...</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And two css lines:

```
.nav-tabs { min-width: 600px; }
.nav-tabs-responsive { overflow: auto; }
```

600px is the point over you will be responsive (you can set it using bootstrap variables)

Comment: Visually, not the best solution but it's working decently and it can be integrated to any webpage almost instantly.

Comment: The `600px` min width may not be enough if you have quite a few tabs.  You may need to increase this value otherwise the tabs will still wrap

Answer (score 5):

Pure CSS only for nav tabs, very simple for small screens:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
     .nav-tabs {
         min-width: 100%;
         display: inline-grid;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution is just 3 lines:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
   .nav-tabs > li {
      width: 100%;
   }
}
```

..but you have to accept the idea of tabs that wrap to more lines in other dimensions.

Of course you can achieve a horizontal scrolling area with `white-space: nowrap` trick but the scrollbars look ugly on desktops so you have to write js code and the whole thing starts becoming no trivial at all!

Comment: You can also add the "nav-justified" class (for responsive); so your UL tag classes will look something like this: <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">...</ul>

Answer (score 0):

I have created a directive in agularJS supported with ng-bootStrap components

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#tabs

here I share the code that I implemented

[https://jsfiddle.net/k1r02/u6gpv4dc/][1]

```
  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/k1r02/u6gpv4dc/
```